# Updating database with foreach is changing the array before updating

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array with names, goal differences and so on for football teams that I want to put in a table, but during the foreach the last key in the array is changed somehow.

Last two keys before foreach

```html
    [18] => Array
        (
            [team_code] => 4
            [team_name] => Newcastle
            [points] => 6
            [goals_for] => 12
            [goals_against] => 22
            [goal_difference] => -10
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [team_code] => 7
            [team_name] => Aston Villa
            [points] => 4
            [goals_for] => 9
            [goals_against] => 17
            [goal_difference] => -8
        )

)
```

After foreach

```html
    [18] => Array
        (
            [team_code] => 4
            [team_name] => Newcastle
            [points] => 6
            [goals_for] => 12
            [goals_against] => 22
            [goal_difference] => -10
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [team_code] => 4
            [team_name] => Newcastle
            [points] => 6
            [goals_for] => 12
            [goals_against] => 22
            [goal_difference] => -10
        )

)
```

My foreach looks like this

```html
  foreach ($teams as $team) {
    $team_code = $team['team_code'];
    $team_name = $team['team_name'];
    $points = $team['points'];
    $goals_for = $team['goals_for'];
    $goals_against = $team['goals_against'];
    $goal_difference = $team['goal_difference'];

    if ($update_query = $conn->query("UPDATE teams SET points = $points, goals_for = $goals_for, goals_against = $goals_against, goal_difference = $goal_difference WHERE team_code = $team_code")) {
      echo 'Updated '.$team_name.'<br>';
    } else {
      $update_query->error;
    }
  }
```

Why is the last key changed? It happens before the query is run, because the row doesn't get updated. All the others update as they should.

Comment: Do you use [a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) somewhere near that code snippet?

Comment: put some echo/print_r/var_dump and check your outputs and SQL statements...

Comment: Thank you @VolkerK, that was it. Strange behavior i think.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to VolkerK I managed to solve it.

I have another foreach with a reference to `&$team` before the foreach, and putting `unset($team)` between the two foreachs solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's anything wrong with your php script. I would take a look at how the array is build before it get to the foreach loop. How is the form for which you enter the data set up. If you are entering multiple teams at once, how are you differentiating the elements